# deviceready not fired after 5 seconds (WP8.1, cordova 3.5)

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

We are creating a new JavaScript->Store Apps->Windows Phone Apps in VS 2013 as described in the tutorial https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows.

But when we run the application in the emulator, we get the following error:

deviceready event is not fired after 5 seconds.

It seems that cordova is not loaded. And hence, we are unable to access any cordova functions.

Kindly help us in resolving the issue.

Thanks,
Gopu.

Comment: You can look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381.aspx Visual Studio extension for building Cordova apps.